# Swift: UIActivityViewController is empty

Tags: ios, swift, share, uiactivityviewcontroller

I trying to create UIActivityViewController. But it appears empty, only with "Copy". No Twitter, no Facebook... Why so? The code is so simple that I don't even know what I do wrong. Could you help me, please.

```
@IBAction func shareButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        let textToShare: String! = "GHJFGEgkjfgejkw"
        let activityViewController: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [textToShare], applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypeMail, UIActivityTypePostToTwitter, UIActivityTypePostToFacebook]    
        self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Just found that issue can occurs because `UIActivityViewController` doesn't own `activityItems` array. So just make sure that it **remains in memory** when you do share action.

Comment: This was the solution for me! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies in your code.

```
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypeMail, UIActivityTypePostToTwitter, UIActivityTypePostToFacebook]
```

`excludedActivityTypes` will exclude these activities from your Activity View Controller.

Try removing `UIActivityTypePostToTwitter` and 
 `UIActivityTypePostToFacebook` from excluded activity types.